# AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm working on a discord.py bot, and I'm having a major issue that i can't seem to fix. I have two commands that have almost the exact same code, but one doesn't work. The following code works:

```
@bot.command(name = 'rees', aliases=['setup'])
async def rees(ctx, guild = None, updateddict = None):
#delete message
    await ctx.message.delete()

    guild = ctx.message.guild.id
    if guild in data:
        await ctx.send('this guild is already set up!')
    elif guild not in data:
        data[guild] = {'pogchampers' : 'false'}
        print(data)
        await ctx.send('guild is set up!')
        with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
    await ctx.send('hello! my name is ehe! use ehehelppls to get a list of my commands!')
```

But the following code gives me an error message

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(ctx, guild = None, updateddict = None):
    print('guild joined')
    guild = ctx.message.guild.id
    if guild in data:
        await print('recently joined guild is already set up!')
    elif guild not in data:
        data[guild] = {'pogchampers' : 'false'}
        print(data)
        await ctx.send('it is done master...')
        with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
    await ctx.send('hello! my name is ehe! use ehehelppls to get a list of my commands!')
```

When this code is run, the following error message is displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Reesj\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\python_bot\bot_here\botcode.py", line 312, in on_guild_join
    guild = ctx.message.guild.id
AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Any idea as to why I would only be getting an error message for *guild = ctx.message.guild.id* in the second block of code and not the first?

Answer (score 0):

You've messed up the parameters of the [`on_guild_join`event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_guild_join). `ctx` is in your case a `guild` object, which of course doesn't have the attribute `message`. You'll need to rewrite your code of your event-handler to fit

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    # do function
```

---

An event is not a command! They have set parameters you can work with! Maybe have a look at the [event-reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference)